# How should I be declaring these functions?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project in VBA that has many modules (10+). I currently have the same functions inside each of the individual modules, but it seems that I could just house them centrally and make them available throughout the entire project. Is there a best practice for this? I don't want them to be available inside of Excel itself (eg, =FunctionCreated(B3)), if it makes a difference. Currently they are declared as Function .

Below is an example of a function that occurs in basically every module.

```
Function IsNumber(ByRef expression As Variant) As Boolean

IsNumber = Not (expression = "") And IsNumeric(expression)

End Function
```

Comment: *I don't want them to be available inside of Excel itself* - can you explain this?  Also, i usually have a module called `genUtilities` or `functions` or whatever where all my functions that are repeatedly called are stored.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Sure. So, if I had a function named "GetNumbersFromString', I don't want users to be able to type '=GetNumbersFromString(B3)'. 
For your module, how do the functions get called on? Are they picked up on just because they exist within the project, or do you need to reference them a particular way?

Comment: You may not need to place a function like this in every module. Try removing it from one module. What happens?

Comment: You may want to consider putting them in an Add-In file instead then (XLAM file format) - then you can access all the functions from any open workbook.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16431876/how-to-restrict-vba-function-only-on-module) will help.

Comment: So you want the function to be available to **any** module, but **not**  available in a worksheet cell??

Comment: @GregViers it seems to work regardless of where it is O_O

Comment: @braX Why would making it an addon do this?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent not OP but that sounds interesting. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the functions/sub  in one module and decorate it with

> 'Option Private Module'

```
Option Explicit

'/ Prevents module's routine(s) from appearing as UDF (still works though)
'/ or Macro candidate.
Option Private Module

Public Function Test(lCtr As Long) As Long
    Test = lCtr + 1
End Function
```

Comment: How do I call this function in a different module?

Comment: `test 1` or `call test(1)`

Comment: `result = test(1)`

Comment: This seems to work fine just by referencing the functions (e.g., IsNumber(cells(i,42).value2).